# Webpage view differently at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css, resolutions

My webpage's view differ at different resolutions. I am using MS Superpreview for testing. Here are the screenshots at 1024x768 and 1280x1024.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27899629/stack/1024x768.png

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27899629/stack/1280x1024.png

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Spanchem - Chemical Cleaning Services, Mumbai India</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen, projection"/>

<!--[if IE 6]>
<![endif]-->


<style type="text/css">

img#pngfix { behavior: url(iepngfix/iepngfix.htc) }

#header {

}

 #header_bg{
background:url(images/header_bg.png) no-repeat; 
width:100%; 
min-height:171px; 
height:auto !important;
height:171px;
z-index:9999; 
border:1px solid red;

}

#top_menu {
left:435px;
position:relative;
top:-115px;
z-index:-999;
color:blue;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<div id="header_bg" ></div>
<div id="top_menu"><img src="images/menu_bg.png" id="pngfix"/></div>

  <div id="m_banner">Banner</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to the reason as to why my pages renders differently at different resolutions and how to correct it.

Comment: Nothing to do with CSS3 here so am editing the tags, you are using wrong positioning, perhaps you should learn it.. `left:435px;
position:relative;
top:-115px;
z-index:-999;`

Comment: I feel my interpretation of relative positioning in the above context is correct. It's positioning of the element relative where it would occur in normal flow of document.  Pls check tab 2 at http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/